# AND operator in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, and-operator

While using AND operator to evaluate the expression in line 6,

```
1. export default function App() {
2.  var isDone = false;
3.  const strikethrough = { textDecoration: "line-through" };
4.  return (
5.    <div className="App">
6.      <h1 style={isDone && strikethrough}>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
7.    </div>
8.   );
9. }
```

when `isDone = false`,
I am getting an error as

> 'The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values,
> not a string. For example, style={‌{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when
> using JSX.

when `isDone = true`, things are working fine.

Somehow the null is not working and in order to check that, I used the following

```
<h1 style={}>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
```

This gives an error that 'JSX attributes must only be assigned a non-empty expression'

I am learning ReactJs from an online course. What's happening here?

Comment: Try `style={isDone ? strikethrough : {}}`

Comment: Yes, I tried 
<h1 style={isDone ? strikethrough : null}>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>, and this works fine 
but why doesn't the && operator work as intended in this case

Comment: It's because `&&` works like this. If whatever's before `&&` is truthy, it'll return whatever's after the `&&`.  If whatever's before `&&` is falsy, it'll return the first value. which is usually `false`. That's what happens in your case. When the condition is false, it returns false and gets assigned to the style attribute

Comment: @TheAlpha93 Thank you for this explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Try to console log your condition.*

You should have this code:

`<h1 style={isDone ? strikethrough : undefined}>`

OR

`<h1 style={isDone ? strikethrough : {}}>`

```
const isDone = true
const strikethrough = 'yes' // or { textDecoration: "line-through" }

console.log(isDone && strikethrough) // return 'yes'
```

VS

```
const isDone = false
const strikethrough = 'yes'

console.log(isDone && strikethrough) // return boolean false
```

Problem is that boolean is not accepted by your `style` props.

More.

If you are using `typescript` you can inspect `props` of your `h1` tag.

There is a `className?: string;` it is mean `string or nothing`.

So, **you can't pass there boolean** from `isDone && strikethrough` (return false).

Comment: Thank you so much, this explanation helped me a lot. I did console log the condition to understand

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign non-empty expression as you already figured out. So you'd need to do something like

```
<h1 style={isDone ? strikethrough : {}}>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
```

in order to have a default style.