# What does && operator and the word variable does in the map of react native official doc example

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

would anyone be able to advise what does `word` in `word && ''` does in example from the link below. I don't quite understand why && operator, a conditional operator is doing inside it.

I have enclosed the code extract below.

```
{text.split(' ').map((word) => word && '').join(' ')}
```

When i remove `word`, so that it become the following:

```
{text.split(' ').map((word) =>  '').join(' ')}
```

I could observe one pizza there before any text is type.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/handling-text-input

Comment: `(word) => word && ''` is the same as `(word) => { if (word) return ''; }`

Comment: Duplicate of [What is “x && foo()”?](/q/6970346/4642212). See [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](/q/9549780/4642212) and the documentation on MDN about [expressions and operators](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators) and [statements](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements).

Answer (score 3):

It's handling the edge case of an empty text.

`"".split(" ")` returns an array of one empty string:

```
> "".split(" ")
[ '' ]
```

We need to make sure `word` is not an empty string before returning a .

Note that empty string is a falsy value in Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

**Word** in that context is used as an inline conditional statement to return . For Instance, in the traditional javascript code would be:

```
if (word) return ''
```

In Reactjs, You may embed expressions in JSX by wrapping them in curly braces. This includes the JavaScript logical && operator. [It can be handy for conditionally including an element](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

So, Given the sentence or text `Hello there Bob`. The map function go through each word and replace the word with , the final output of the given text would be

Check [and-operator-in-reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62714334/and-operator-in-reactjs) or [dont-understand-in-this-javascript-jsx-syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63420039/i-dont-understand-in-this-javascript-jsx-syntax) or [understanding-the-use-of-and-in-a-react-component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61166026/understanding-the-use-of-in-a-react-component). Learn [javascript logics](https://javascript.info/logical-operators) and [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND)

Answer (score 0):

With the `&&` operator you are ensuring that the first second condition is run **only** if the `word` value is truthy. Empty string `""` is a [falsy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).

Mostly irrelevant in your case, it would help when you have an input with **multiple consecutive whitspaces**. If you do not use `&&`, then `' '` will be considered as one more character.

```js
let text1 = "I love 0 pizza a lot   - false";
let text2 = "I love 0 pizza a lot   - false";

let newText = text1.split(' ').map((word) => word && '').join(' ');
let newText2 = text2.split(' ').map((word) => '').join(' ');

console.log(newText);
console.log(newText2);
```